# jsonp : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I need to load an aspx page that returns a string of text using jsonp since it is a cross domain call. The target page will be loaded inside a div tag and displayed as a modal window on the source page.

I am using a test form to pass 3 parameters that the target page expects, a submit button, very simple.

When I submit the page, I get an error message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

When I click on the error I see the error points to this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

This is the first time I am working with json/ jsonp, and I am not sure how to fix this error. Is it possible to get some help to figure this out?

My invoking page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "Details",
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                url: "http://localhost:81/order-error.aspx",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { 'order': $("#order").val(), 'site': $("#site").val(), 'env': $("#env").val() },                    
                success: function (r) {
                    $("#dialog").html(r.d);
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="order" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="site" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="env" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My target/ response page (order-error.aspx):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;            
        display: inline-block
    }
    .label {
        position:relative;
        float:left;            
        top:0;
        margin-right:5px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div class="order">
        <div class="label">Web Order#: </div>
        <div id="orderno" runat="server" class="value"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="error">
        <div class="label">Message: </div>
        <div class="value">
            <asp:Label ID="lblOrderError" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind:

```
Partial Class order_error
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim siteKey As String = String.Empty
    Dim orderId As String = String.Empty

    siteKey = Request.QueryString("site").Trim
    orderId = Request.QueryString("order").Trim

    Me.lblOrderError.Text = Functions.GetAXErrorMessage(siteKey, orderId)

    Me.orderno.InnerText = orderId.Trim
    lblOrderError.Visible = True

End Sub
End Class
```

The output html of order-error.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />               
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div class="order">
        <div class="label">Web Order#: </div>
        <div id="orderno" class="value">A1G759</div>
    </div>
    <div class="error">
        <div class="label">Message: </div>
        <div class="value">
            <span id="lblOrderError"><Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Fault">
<Code />
<Reason>
<Text xml:lang="EN-US">User is not authorized for this Endpoint.</Text>
</Reason>
</Fault></span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
{"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"757708942b1d4af892b199f3590d85f5"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:63737/17a3dfffdc8f48ad9496d260bd296120/browserLink" async="async"></script>   
<!-- End Browser Link -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If `order-error.aspx` is literally returning HTML, this is the problem. JSONP requests assume the response from the server is valid JSON, not HTML.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, actually its supposed to be valid javascript since it gets included as a script.

Comment: Can you post the actual HTTP response body you are getting?

Comment: From the looks of it, either JSON is being returned by the server with strings improperly escaped, or you think it's returning JSON and it's actually returning a full web page.

Comment: It is returning a full web page. Can this be corrected so it can receive the page? I added the output html of the target page.

Comment: @Gerg Burghardt, I posted the response already e.g. "The output html of order-error.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly caused by your AJAX call return HTML instead of JSON.

In the `success` handler you have `$("#dialog").html(r.d);`. Here you try to parse the output of the call (`r`) to an object (`r.d` forces this), which fails for obvious reasons.

You should return JSON from your AJAX method, possibly using an HTTP handler or WebAPI.